# GEF Connection and PropertyChangeListener

Tags: java, connection, handle, eclipse-gef, propertychangelistener

I'm writing on a eclipse plugin based on RCP and GEF that displays streetmaps. 
Nodes are the cities and Connections are supposed to be the streets. My Connections have several options like width, color or name and they can be changed over the property panel. My problem is, that AbstractConnectionEditPart doesn't implements the PropertyChangeListener and is generally handled in a different way than the nodes. I've found out, that GEF has a abstract class named ConnectionHandle but I've no idea how to "connect" it to my controller of the connection.

Does anybody has further information or can provide a working code snippet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GEF edit parts don't implement any kind of listener by default. It is you job to either subclass the `EditPart` and implement a listener, or create an external listener to your model and update the `EditPart` when the model changes. You can [check out my tutorials](http://www.vainolo.com/tutorials/gef-tutorials/) for more information on how this can be done (and sorry for the self-promotion, but the solution is there, so no need to write it again here).

Comment: Thanks alot, with your tutorials i figured it out.